# OOP: method name classification

Tags: oop, methods

Lately I have been struggling with method names in OOP and I decided to sort that out. For that purpose, I am trying to classify names of methods from natural language point of view. So far, I have figured out these categories:

1] **Commands:**

```
elem_list.append('x')
bank_account.deposit(50)
game.get_score()
```

`append`, `deposit`, `get_score` are commands here. You ask objects to do something (or ask interpreter to do something with them - depends on point of view). These methods contain a verb in various forms: just **verb**, **verb + noun**, **verb + adjective + noun**, sometimes **noun + verb** (to further clarify meaning of the verb). Commands are probably the most common names.

2] **Queries:**

```
connection.is_open()
snake.is_dead()
window.can_hide()
```

These are not so common. Their form is **passive-verb + adjective** (this form can be surely described better, I am not a native English guy). Basically, here you query about a state of an object.

The following are categories I am not sure about because I haven't really seen lots of method names like that (it can be my limited experience though):

3] **Declarations:**

```
button.widget_selected(event)
window.screen_changed(screen)
```

Here you notify an object that something has happened and expect it to do its job. The method is basically an event handler. The form is usually something like **noun + passed-tense-verb.** I am unsure about this category because you can transform it into a command just by prepending a verb e.g. `handle`: `button.handle_widget_selected(event)` which seems to be more natural when calling the method.

4] **Noun-names**

```
snake.crash_animation()
game.introduction()
```

I don't really like these because I think nouns should be reserved for data. And they can be transformed into the first category simply.

So my question is if you somehow agree with this classification and whether you consider names in the third and fourth category good or bad with respect to OOP paradigm.

Comment: It probably will be closed I guess and I understand why. I just tried to get some feedback on this cause I am not that experienced in OOP.

Comment: If you'd mentioned a specific language, you could most likely have tailored this question within the remit of SO, but I'm guessing it's a bit late now.

Comment: This has a chance of degenerating into a quasi-religious discussion, so will likely be closed before that happens. Verb-Noun names seem to be preferred for action methods, though at times I use Noun-Verb to control sorting despite being a bit awkward in English. There are many style guides on the web.

Comment: Remember that if a question is closed, it enters the Reopen queue on every question edit. A re-worked question can be reopened if reviewers think it now meets best practice for question asking.

Comment: I have modified the question to at least contain a question so, please, if you could consider reopening...

Comment: @middaparka: I don't think this stuff depends on language. It might depend on a paradigm but not a language.

Comment: @chime Different languages and indeed frameworks often have their own conventions/coding styles for such things, hence I was suggesting that as a means of reining your question in beyond the realms of the "one true method naming convention to rule them all" approach. (Hence hopefully avoiding the question being closed as "not constructive".) :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a `style guide` or `coding standard`.

e.g.

> [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (common referred Python style guide)
>
> [Google JS styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)

Having said that, imo it's better to be consistent throughout your coding than mixing in a style guide (stick to what you started with or refactor everything). Having your own scheme is fine, but you'd rather spend time on productivity.

Comment: well, that describes if I should use camelCase or underscores and stuff like that, right? Could you point to specific part "How to formulate method names" or something like that?

Comment: @clime it all depends on the language you are going to use.

Comment: You should have highlighted the best parts of those links. As a result in 2016, the Google Styleguide points to an error, and the PEP-8 one lands me in an index which I don't know where to go from.